# I cannot exit Vim, I hit escape and tried :q :x :qx

Tags: vim

I cannot exit Vim, I hit escape and tried :q :x :qx

None of the other questions are working, I am running windows 8.

Comment: what I usually do is to press CTRL + (C or X or Z).

Comment: You need to hit Enter after `:q`.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, I did hit enter.

Comment: Probably you accidently changed your keyboard layout?

Answer (score 14):

### To escape from [Vim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_(text_editor))

1. `ctrl+c` to *interrupt current task* and return to the command mode
2. `:q![ENTER]` *to quit, bypassing save prompt*

Comment: @AlexisLynneHandler If it works for you, please [mark the answer as accepted.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5235)

Comment: @AlexisLynneHandler, always mark it when its right :)

Answer (score -1):

`:q!` then `Enter` to quit without saving

`:wq` then `Enter` to save and quit

Comment: I had to cntrl+C first